# character recognition with gesture detector

Tags: android, gesture-recognition, handwriting-recognition

I want to recognize alphanumeric characters and numbers with a gesture detector. I browsed the web for existing examples or libraries but I haven't found much suitable results.

Does anyone knows some libraries or existing examples for character recognizing with a gesture detector? (I think sophisticated tools like tessaract are too much overhead for simple character recognition.)

Thanks

Comment: I suggest saving the gesture to a temp bitmap first (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/gesture/Gesture.html#toBitmap(int, int, int, int, int)) and then use any of the character recognition libraries that work with images to read it for you (like http://sourceforge.net/p/javaocr/source/ci/master/tree/ or https://github.com/rmtheis/tess-two). Disclaimer: I've never done this and not sure what the performance is going to be like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MyScript is a commercial library for character recognition whith several SDKs: http://myscript.com/technology/#developer-kits

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try.